# How to send a DM to the user executing the command and sending to a channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am working on a command called `report`, and it is supposed to do two things.

**1. Send a(n) (Embed) DM to the user calling the command.**

**2. Send a message to the #reports channel.**

Right now I have been focusing on the DM part, not trying to use embed right now, (although it should be easy with a generator). I have tried many methods but they all don't work for me, in other words, they don't send a DM to me or a user at all.
I should mention I have a cog.py, but I am using the bot.py for this right now. For my prefix, I am using a `+` specified in my config.py, but **I would like to force use a `!` for this command if that is possible.**

**EDIT:** Here is what worked for me, I had to add the `(pass_context=True)` to the decorator.

```
# report command
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, value):
    await user.send(f"**{value}**")
    await user.send(Sent by {ctx.author.display_name}")
try:
    bot.run(token)
except:
    pass
```

I have also tried the following methods:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEo7FZpe-VA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uyctSEjJ8r0

If anyone could provide me with some ways I could check if I am missing any components on how I am doing this right, or a solution to sending a DM and possibly a message to a channel that would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: Apparently doing commands, in general, isn't working, so once I fix that the resources above should work too.**

Comment: `await user.send(Sent by {ctx.author.display_name}")`: you forgot `f"` at the beginning of your string (don't know if it'll solve your problem)

Comment: @Mr_Spaar it didn't sadly, weird that nothing hasn't worked for me... Ima test and see if i am doing the command stuff wrong

Comment: Also, you don't really need the `try ... else ...` statement. Maybe you'll have an error message that'll help you understand your problem if you remove it (and doing commands work well, people just make basic mistakes)